# SqliteConstraintException Android

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

I have a proble with a SqliteConstraintException.
My db is like that

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_1 =
   "create table table_1 (uid integer primary key autoincrement, "
+ table_1.c1 + " TEXT,"
+ table_1.c2 + " integer,"
+ table_1.c3 + " TEXT," 
+ table_1.c4 + " TEXT,"
+ table_1.c5 + " integer);";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_2 = 
        "create table table_2 (uid integer primary key autoincrement, "
+ table_2.c1 + " TEXT,"
+ table_2.c2 + " integer,"
+ table_2.c3 + " TEXT);";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_3 = 
        "create table table_3 (uid integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "uid_table_1 integer, "
        + "uid_table_2 integer, "

+ "FOREIGN KEY(uid_table_1) REFERENCES table_1(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE, " 
+ "FOREIGN KEY(uid_table_2) REFERENCES table_2(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE);";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_4 = 
        "create table table_4 (uid integer primary key autoincrement, "
+ "uid_table_2 integer,"
+ "FOREIGN KEY(uid_table_2) REFERENCES table_2(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE);";
```

And i use in my SQLiteOpenHelper to enable foreign key constraints

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
super.onOpen(db);
if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
// Enable foreign key constraints
db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
}
```

But when i want to delete on row of the table_2, i get SqliteConstraintException.
Can you help me please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like most of your tables reference each other. if you want to delete a row in Table 2 that is used as the foreign key in a different table, you need to delete the records that reference it. so delete records from tables 3 and 4 that have a foreign key reference to the row you are trying to delete in 2 and THEN call delete for that row.

Comment: So It is correct if i do that  `mDb.beginTransaction();
  try{
   mDb.delete("table_3", "uid_table_2=" + uid, null);
   mDb.delete("table_4", "uid_table_2=" + uid, null);
   this.mDb.delete("table_2", "uid = " + uid, null);
  }catch(Exception e){
   
  }finally{
   mDb.endTransaction();
  }`

Comment: i forget to add `mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();`

Comment: if i understand correctly, you don't NEED to begin or end a transaction. every call is automatically wrapped in a transaction. the only time i do it manually is if i'm modifying the database in a loop. it can be significantly faster to begin a transaction, do a couple hundred inserts or deletes, then end it - but with just a couple, it doesn't get you much but makes your code more cluttered